# Use iPhone camera as webcam on PC

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, camera, webcam

I would like to use the iphone camera as webcam on PC programatically.
Is this possible ?
If it is possible can anyone suggest me any example or giv me few ideas on how to go foward on this.

Thanks
Abhishek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I can imagine the story (sorry, it's not trivial to implement, but at least it's certainly possible):

1. Use the AVFoundation and CoreVideo frameworks to capture live video data from the device;
2. Open a TCP/IP connection (you can use raw BSD sockets, `CFNetwork`, etc.) and stream the video data through that connection;
3. Write a client application that runs on the PC, receives the data and reconstructs it on the screen (for example). There are various libraries perfectly usable for media playback... You can also make a kernel module if you're using Linux or a driver if you're using Windows and make your client application pretend to be a webcam.